# Calling WCF callback service from a ASP.NET web app hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis-7, callback

I have to develop a WCF callback service which will be accessed by the ASP.Net web application hosted in IIS or public internet.  In this implementation clients should keep getting the updates from the service, so I thought of using WsDualhttpBinding, but I found few disadvantages of  WCF callback service over internet. 
How to use a WCF Dual Service over the internet?  Any one please suggest any sample application for this?

Comment: You could ditch WCF and use something like SignalR or XSockets.Net

Comment: Is it not possible to get the updates with WCF Polling? If it is possible, how the service will stop polling when the client is disconnected?

Comment: The client would have to poll the service with ajax polling. Not the other way around.